# Send commands to android app from server

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to make an app that sends back the data from the phone only when the server ask's for it.
How am i supposed to implement this?

> i.e **The server should trigger the code (uploading activity) in the
>   app.**

I thought of using *GCM* or  *C2DM* to trigger it but this gives notification in the status bar which i don't want.

Comment: The notification in gcm is not compulsory.. you can just get the message alone and use it for other purposes too.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Messaging doesn't create a notification in the status bar. You do (if you want to). When a GCM message arrives to the device, application code is executed, and the developer of the application can decide what to do with the content of the message. One option is to create a notification in the status bar, but nothing forces you to do it. You can process the GCM message silently.